# What is the function to jump from Rascal to a certain Location in IDE

Tags: rascal

If I have a Rascal visualization with location information (e.g. to start/endline of a Java Method), how can I jump into the IDE and highlight the selected lines?

So essentially how can I get the same behavior as clicking on a printed loc in the Rascal Console?

E.g:

```
onMouseDown(bool (int butnr, map[KeyModifier,bool] modifiers)   {
    jumpIntoEclipseHighlightLoc(loc);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for the `edit` functions in `util::Editors`.

Comment: Thanks that is very quick, and from Mr Klint himself. I still need to read some papers from you ;-)